# How to count substrings separarted by a delimitter in a dataframe column and push the value into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

So, I have a dataframe like this

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([['indiejesse.d@gmail.com; pamelasilvera69@gmail.com; kristinestringer69@gmail.com', 'conference meeting ...']], columns=['CC', 'Body'])
```

The column "CC" contains a list of emails separated by ";". I want to iterate through the "CC" column, count the number of emails separated by ";" in each of the rows and add a new column let's say "CC_count" after CC which contains the number CC emails of each row.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just count the amount of `;` with [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html), add one and assign to a new column:

```
df['CC_count'] = df.CC.str.count(';').add(1)
```

---

```
print(df)
                                               CC                    Body  \
0  indiejesse.d@gmail.com; pamelasilvera69@gmail....  conference meeting ...   

   CC_count  
0         3
```